# Python "render" a text like a terminal emulator

Tags: python-3.x, email

I'm currently writing a [set of tools](https://github.com/dangrie158/py-toolbox) I use for my research. One of those tools is a way to automatically send notifications once a long-running process terminates or stalles. These messages can be E-Mails and can capture the output that is produced by the piece of code for example (or [more examples](https://py-toolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/notification.html)):

```py
>>> stream = io.StringIO()
>>> notify = NotifyViaStream("testtask", stream)
>>> # set a custom template used to stringify the notifications
>>> notify.notification_template = "{task} {reason} {output}"
>>> with notify.when_done():
...     # potentially long-running process
...     print('testoutput')
>>> stream.getvalue()
'testtask done testoutput'
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve now is that especially long-running tasks like to print progress bars to inform the user about the current status. Thus they often use a `\r` carriage return to move the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrite the whole line to update the progressbar. However, when sending (text) emails, this caputured output (containing the `\r`s will of course not be rendered like this. Instead each update is printed in a new line, resulting in messy outputs, for example:

```
running RTEDataset fs=(3, 4, 5), nb_f=128
Epoch 1/3

 1/77 [..............................] - ETA: 8:12 - loss: 1.0988 - acc: 0.3750                                                                               
 2/77 [..............................] - ETA: 4:21 - loss: 0.9525 - acc: 0.5156                                                                               
 3/77 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:03 - loss: 0.8636 - acc: 0.5625                                                                               
 4/77 [>.............................] - ETA: 2:24 - loss: 0.9153 - acc: 0.5312                                                                               
 5/77 [>.............................] - ETA: 2:01 - loss: 0.9294 - acc: 0.5250                                                                               
 6/77 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:45 - loss: 0.9078 - acc: 0.5417                                                                               
 7/77 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:33 - loss: 0.9101 - acc: 0.5268 
 ... and so on
```

What is the best way to "pre-render" the output to be what you would get on a terminal emulator? Is there anything smarter to just use a regex to match everything from the start of the line to the \r and replacing it with an empty string? This would already not work if the next line would not completely overwrite the last, for example:

`test\routput\rback` would get printed as `backut` on a terminal but as `back` using this simple approach.

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this without using external libraries (maybe using `ncursed` or even on the client side in the email client?)

**Bonus Question**: would you make the behaviour configurable to explicitly not handle (or even remove) carriage returns? And if so, what would be your preferred default value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I could not find anything in the standard libs, so I coded this function that does exactly what I need:

```
def render_text(text: str, maxwidth: int = -1) -> str:
    r"""
    Attempt to render a text like an (potentiall infinitely wide)
    terminal would.

    Thus carriage-returns move the cursor to the start of
    the line, so subsequent characters overwrite the previous.

    .. doctest::

        >>> render_text('asd\rbcd\rcde\r\nqwe\rert\n123', maxwidth=2)
        'cd\ne \ner\nt \n12\n3'

    :param text: Input text to render
    :param maxwidth: if > 0, wrap the text to the specified maximum length
        using the textwrapper library
    """
    # create a buffer for the rendered ouput text
    outtext = StringIO()
    for char in text:
        if char == "\r":
            # seek to one character past the last new line in
            # the current rednered text. This woks nicely because
            # rfind will return -1 if no newline is found this
            # this will seek to the beginning of the stream
            outtext.seek(outtext.getvalue().rfind("\n") + 1)

            # continue to the next character, dont write he carriage return
            continue
        elif char == "\n":
            # a newline moves the cursor to the end of he buffer
            # the newline itself is written below
            outtext.seek(len(outtext.getvalue()))

        # write he current character to the buffer
        outtext.write(char)

    rendered_text = outtext.getvalue()

    # connditionnally wrap the text after maxwidth characters
    if maxwidth > 0:
        rendered_text = textwrap.fill(rendered_text, maxwidth)
    return rendered_text
```

You can either copy this code or use my implementation in the [io module of my Framework](https://py-toolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/io.html#pytb.io.render_text)